# $H_p(K)$ and $H_p(K^r)$ are isomorphic

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, group-isomorphism

Let $K^r$ be the r-skeleton of the simplicial complex $K$.Let $0\leq p <r$. I need to show that $H_p(K)$ is isomorphic to $H_p(K^r)$. All p-simplices of $K$ are simplices of$K^r$. So, $C_p(K)$ should be isomorphic to $C_p(K^r)$. How do I go  forward with this? Any hints are much appreciated

Comment: Consider the long exact sequence corresponding to the pair $(K, K^r)$.

Comment: What kind of homology you are interested in? If it is simplicial homology, then the complex $C_\bullet (K^r)$ literally coincides with the complex $C_\bullet (K)$ up to degree $r$, so the claim is obvious.

Comment: @Alejo yes simplicial homology. So isomorphic chain groups implies isomorphic homology groups?

Comment: @Donald Edwards NO, NOT AT ALL! But you have much more in your case: the differentials are the same.

Comment: @Alejo I would comment that an isomorphism of chain complexes should include appropriate isomorphisms of differentials, if we're working in the category of chain complexes, nothing else should be considered an isomorphism there. Confusion only seems to occur if you assume that a chain complex somehow lives in R-mod for some ring R (where abelian groups are the case where $R \cong \mathbb{Z}$.) where the maps between groups (the differentials, are more or less ignored.

Answer (score 2):

OK, I will post it as an answer. If we are talking about simplicial homology, then the claim is rather obvious. Indeed, the simplicial complex $K^r$ has the same simplices as $K$ in degrees $p \le r$ and nothing else starting from degree $p = r+1$. So the chain complex for $K^r$ looks like
$$0\to 0 \to C_r (K) \xrightarrow{d_r} C_{r-1} (K) \xrightarrow{d_{r-1}} C_{r-1} (K) \to \cdots \to C_1 (K) \xrightarrow{d_1} C_0 (K) \to 0$$
(I put zeros starting from $p=r+1$ since I discard the degenerate simplices; but it doesn't really matter.) Here the differentials are the same as in the complex $C_\bullet (K)$. Hence
$$H_p (K^r) = H_p (K) = \ker d_p/\operatorname{im} d_{p+1} \quad \text{for }p \le r-1.$$
Note that starting from degree $r$, the homology will differ in general: you get $H_p (K^r) = \ker d_r$ and $H_p (K) = \ker d_r / \operatorname{im} d_{r+1}$, and $H_p (K^r) = 0$ for $p > r$.

In general, if you have $K' \subset K$, then you will obtain some **subcomplex** $C_\bullet (K') \subset C_\bullet (K)$. This means that you have subgroup inclusions $C_p (K') \subset C_p (K)$ such that the differentials in $C_\bullet (K')$ are the restrictions of differentials in $C_\bullet (K)$. Then you indeed may consider the long exact sequence associated to the pair $(K, K')$, but your particular case is much easier.

---

Degree-wise isomorphisms $C_p \cong B_p$, or in general maps $f_p\colon C_p\to B_p$, are not very meaningful. To conclude that these maps induce maps in homology, you need these maps to commute with the differentials of your complexes.

For example, two complexes
$$0\to \mathbb{Z} \xrightarrow{0} \mathbb{Z} \to 0 \quad\text{and}\quad 0\to \mathbb{Z} \xrightarrow{\mathrm{id}} \mathbb{Z} \to 0$$
have different homology...